# Improving my stock comment baseline for "need more info"

Tags: discussion, comments

I have a basic pattern I use for commenting on questions that are missing some crucial bit of info, which looks like this: "[stuff] Please edit that into your question." Obviously, I customize it to mention exactly *what* needs to be edited in.

But this only gets an edit maybe 15% of the time, a direct comment reply **stating the necessary info** another 45%, a reply asking for more information on what more information is needed * perhaps 5%, and nothing at all maybe 35% of the time (very roughly). Is there a good way to make this punchier and more effectively direct posters to the point that the *question itself* really needs to be edited to be better-written? It gets old editing in the stuff they could have themselves, especially when I'm commenting from review on a question I frankly don't care much about.

<sub>*This is actually why I asked on meta in the first place **.

**Not really.</sub>

Comment: I don't know any magic that convinces folks that the amount of effort put into creating their question and the quality of the question has direct bearing on the quality of answers that they could receive. Keep fighting the good fight though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Well, obviously I don't expect them to start asking better questions in future, that would just be silly! But it would be nice for them to save time, mine and theirs, by editing it in instead of replying with it....

Comment: Have you tried putting the request to edit at the front of your comment?  "Please edit your question to contain/include/describe...".  Heck, if you have characters left, you could put it at the end too.  (And thanks for trying.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I haven't yet. Worth a shot, though.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/285196/edit) and include xyz?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Maybe, but manually linking that would get kind of old. Is there a handy little auto-link setup somewheres?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. Maybe it could get added to the "magic links" set that converts things like `[dba.se]` to [dba.se] if there was enough demand.

Comment: `[edit]` is the magic link for "edit the post to which this comment is attached", @Martin and Nathan.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Woot woot! Let's do this thing.

Comment: @josh. Oh, cool, so the functionality does exist. Testing. [edit]